# Uninstalled and installed python and now facing issues with pip

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I use a mac and I switched from python2 to python3 recently. Post doing that I couldn't install jupyter on my laptop due to some dependency issues. After a lot of trial and errors, I just uninstalled Python 3 and installed it with brew instead.

I used the following guides to uninstall [1](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-python-on-mac), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references).

Post that I installed jupyter again and now I'm facing this issue:

`$ pip install --index-url '..' --trusted-host '..' jupyter`

This is how I usually install packages on my laptop behind a firewall and it works. But now I'm getting the following exception:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 311, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.populate_link(self.finder, upgrade_allowed, self.require_hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 225, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 879, in find_requirement
    req.name, specifier=req.specifier, hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 861, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 791, in find_all_candidates
    collected_links = self._link_collector.collect_links(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/collector.py", line 541, in collect_links
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/collector.py", line 493, in _get_pages
    page = _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/collector.py", line 339, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/collector.py", line 146, in _get_html_response
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 426, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 199, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 470, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 420, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None
```

I have set the proxy and it can be seen using `env`. I've also tried:

```
export http_proxy="http://<hostname>:<port>"
export https_proxy="https://<hostname>:<port>"
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant? https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5297

Comment: I tried `--proxy`, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, what helped was `unset https_proxy http_proxy`.