# Why is ProxySchemeUnknown error throwing while installing JayDeBeApi using pip?

Tags: python, pip, jaydebeapi

Pip install is throwing error while installing package JayDeBeApi. I tried to edit Conf file. Tried uninstall and reinstall Python, it is throwing the same error over and over again. Can someone please help?

```
$ pip3 install --proxy=https://[ID]:[PWD]@ProxyURL:Proxyport JayDeBeApi

Looking in indexes: https://jfrog.xxxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple
Collecting JayDeBeApi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 410, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 308, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 198, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 449, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 400, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme xxxxx
```

Comment: Try [`unset https_proxy http_proxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951610/7976758). Use search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown%3A+Not+supported+proxy+scheme

Comment: @phd It did not work. But why proxy needs to be unset. It's required right?

Comment: 1. It's required if you have a proxy. 2. Config or env vars must point to you real proxy, and it seems you have wrong URLs, something like `xxxxx://`

Comment: @phd yes, I have a proxy. That url is something I edited to hide my company name.
my config is like this. 
`[global]  
index-url = https://jfrog.abcd.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple. 
cert = Users\[ID].aws\[name].pem. 
trusted-host = pypi.python.org  
               pypi.org  
               files.pythonhosted.org  
proxy = https://[ID]:[PWD]@[ProxyURL]:[Port]`  


My env vars are like this

`export PYTHONPATH="/Users/[Userid]/PycharmProjects/Snowflake Project"
export HTTP_PROXY='[TID]:[PWD]@[ProxyURL]:[Port]'
export HTTPS_PROXY='[TID]:[PWD]@[ProxyURL]:[Port]'`

Comment: Try to add `https://` in env vars: `export HTTPS_PROXY='https://[TID]:[PWD]@[ProxyURL]:[Port]'` and `export HTTP_PROXY='https://[TID]:[PWD]@[ProxyURL]:[Port]'`